# Manual configuration of Spring Data R2DBC throws Unable to make field accessible

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc

I need to create my R2DBC configuration manually because the application has 2 database connections. When using auto configuration and connecting to just one database, the repositories work correctly. When using a manual config, the app throws while creating the repo implementations with:

`Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private java.lang.String java.net.URL.protocol accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @69a61a00`

The entity has an attribute of type `URL`

Here's the configuration:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories(
    entityOperationsRef = "postgresR2dbcEntityOperations",
    basePackages = ["com.acme.somepackage"],
)
@EnableR2dbcAuditing
class R2DBCConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.r2dbc.postgres")
    fun postgresR2dbcProperties() = R2dbcProperties()

    @Bean
    fun postgresConnectionFactory(
        @Qualifier("postgresR2dbcProperties") props: R2dbcProperties
    ): ConnectionFactory {
        val host = ConnectionFactoryOptions
            .parse(props.url)
            .getRequiredValue(Option.valueOf<String>("host")) as String

        return PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration
            .builder()
            .host(host)
            .username(props.username)
            .password(props.password)
            .schema("myschema")
            .build()
            .let { PostgresqlConnectionFactory(it) }
    }

    @Bean
    fun postgresR2dbcEntityOperations(
        @Qualifier("postgresConnectionFactory") connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory,
    ): R2dbcEntityOperations {
        val mappingContext = R2dbcMappingContext()
        val dialect = DialectResolver.getDialect(connectionFactory)
        val converters = dialect.converters.toMutableList()
        converters.addAll(R2dbcCustomConversions.STORE_CONVERTERS)

        val storeConversions = StoreConversions.of(dialect.getSimpleTypeHolder(), converters)
        val customConverters = listOf(
            // customer converters
        )
        val customConversions = R2dbcCustomConversions(storeConversions, customConverters)
        val mappingConverter = MappingR2dbcConverter(mappingContext, customConversions)
        val strategy = DefaultReactiveDataAccessStrategy(PostgresDialect.INSTANCE, mappingConverter)
        val client = DatabaseClient.builder()
            .connectionFactory(connectionFactory)
            .bindMarkers(PostgresDialect.INSTANCE.bindMarkersFactory)
            .build()

        return R2dbcEntityTemplate(client, strategy)
    }
}
```

Is there something that the auto-config is doing that I'm missing that will fix this?

Thanks.

Full stack:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private java.lang.String java.net.URL.protocol accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @69a61a00
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:779)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:536)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:703)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:379)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.lambda$createAndRegisterProperty$3(AbstractMappingContext.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:588)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:703)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.doAddPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:379)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:280)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$6(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:282)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.support.R2dbcRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(R2dbcRepositoryFactoryBean.java:159)
```